# Why does Yahoo reject Firebase's OAuth callback domain (redirection endpoint)?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, yahoo-api

I'm using Firebase Auth for Google, Facebook, Twitter, GitHub, and Microsoft. Yahoo doesn't work, it rejects the callback domain. Firebase provides the callback domain `languagetwo-cd94d.firebaseapp.com`.

[image]

The error message is "Callback Uri must be a valid URL."

[image]

I added `https://` and it's accepted.

[image]

But when I try to login I get an error message `Developers: Please check the redirect URI in your request and submit again.`

[image]

I contacted the Yahoo help desk they said, "Unfortunately, we are not able to assist with issues relating to OAuth2." Any idea why Yahoo doesn't work with a Firebase callback domain?

Comment: its because it asks for a URI, not a hostname.

Comment: Daniel, a hostname can be a URI. URI is a broad term.

Comment: URI according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier require a scheme.

Comment: Yes, https:// is a URL scheme, and a type of URI.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you fixed this already but I ran into the same problem as you did, and I think I fixed it by looking at what the redirect URI is for Facebook in Firebase's console. I compared the two and tried adding /__auth/handler at the end of the redirect URI and it worked. In this case your URI would be:

https://languagetwo-cd94d.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, your solution worked ok, but it failed in the next step, the response returned UID but not email. Do you know how to get email? I mean this command: `app.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)`